# Seleccion Multiple de Rows Windows Form c#

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

```
  int rowCount = dataGridView2.RowCount; // Obtener el número total de filas en el DataGridView

  if (rowCount >= 6)
  {
      int selectedRowIndex = dataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex; // Obtener la fila actualmente seleccionada

      if (selectedRowIndex >= 0 && selectedRowIndex < 6)
      {
          if (selectedRowIndex == 0)
          {
              txtDniEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
              txtApellido2Esposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              txtApellidoEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              txtNombreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
              txtPaisEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
          }
          else if (selectedRowIndex == 1)
          {
              txtDniEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
              txtApellido2Esposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              txtApellidoEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              txtNombreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
              txtPaisEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
          }
          else if (selectedRowIndex == 2)
          {
              txtDniMadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
              txtApellidoMadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              txtApellido2MadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              txtNombreMadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
              
          }
          else if (selectedRowIndex == 3)
          {
              txtDniPadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
              txtApellidoPadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              txtApellido2PadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              txtNombreMadreEsposa.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
          }
          else if (selectedRowIndex == 4)
          {
              txtDniPadreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
              txtApellidoPadreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              txtApellido2PadreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              txtNombrePadreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
          }
          else if (selectedRowIndex == 5)
          {
              txtDniMadreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
              textBox3.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              textBox4.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              txtMadreEsposo.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
          }

          // Realiza aquí las operaciones que necesites con los datos asignados a los TextBox
      }
      else
      {
          
      }
```

Tengo este codigo que funciona cuando Selecciono una sola Row y los ingresa correctamente donde van,ahora el tema es que tengo que seleccionar 1x1 , no hay una forma de elegir la primer row y se que se repita esa accion para las otras 5  debajo de ella en el orden que estan? Como ven cada una tiene textbox diferentes , o si hay alguna guia o video de youtube donde podria recaudar informacion sobre como hacerlo o si o si me va tocar siempre hacer 1x1 es un

Comment: Y donde estas iterando para hacerlo para mas de una fila??